# Automate breaking of history in insert mode

Tags: insert-mode, undo-redo

I started to learn ViM one month ago, so I'm not a ViM expert.

My question is: if I make some changes in insert mode (let's say I type some text, then I delete the last two words and finally type some other words) and then I press `<ESC> u` the entire text I typed in Insert mode disappears. I know the existence of the `<CTRL-G> u` command, which breaks the undo history, but I find it annoying typing `<CTRL-G> u` every single time I delete something. Is there a way to automate the execution of that command every time I press a key (`<SPACE>`, `<BS>`, ...) in insert mode?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define insert mode mappings for those keys by prepending `<c-g>u`:

```
:inoremap <space> <c-g>u<space>
:inoremap <bs>    <c-g>u<bs>
:inoremap <c-w>   <c-g>u<c-w>
" etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

See [`:help ins-special-special`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#ins-special-special), that section has some specific examples on using `inoremap` to trigger `<C-G>u` automatically for specific keystrokes such as backspace or newline.

> An example for using `CTRL-G u`:
>
> ```
>     :inoremap <C-H> <C-G>u<C-H>
> ```
>
> This redefines the backspace key to start a new undo sequence.  You can now undo the effect of the backspace key, without changing what you typed before that, with `CTRL-O u`.  Another example:
>
> ```
>     :inoremap <CR> <C-]><C-G>u<CR>
> ```
>
> This breaks undo at each line break.  It also expands abbreviations before this.